How to decrease the time for timed out in Heroku?
I am currently using an app on Heroku that utilizes several dynos. Unfortunately, I've encountered an issue where these dynos are becoming idle, unresponsive, and only terminate after 24 hours. I am looking for a solution that would reduce this idle time significantly. My ideal scenario would be for these dynos to automatically terminate if they have been idle for a shorter period of time, such as an hour, 30 minutes, or even 2 hours, as opposed to the current 24 hours. Is there a way to configure Heroku to achieve this?

Heroku does not provide a built-in feature to customize the idle timeout settings for dynos. However, you can solve this problem by implementing a custom script within your application that tracks activity and shuts down the dyno if it becomes idle for your specified time frame.
I don't have access to Heroku at the moment. But this should get you close to what you want to do:
import requests
from time import sleep, time

# Put your Heroku API key and app name here
HEROKU_API_KEY = 'your_heroku_api_key'
APP_NAME = 'your_app_name'

# URL to manage your app's dynos
HEROKU_DYNOS_URL = f'https://api.heroku.com/apps/{APP_NAME}/formation'

# Headers for the Heroku API
HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {HEROKU_API_KEY}',
}

# Track idle time
last_activity_time = time()
IDLE_TIMEOUT = 3600  # 1 hour in seconds

def check_activity():
    # Check if the app is idle (placeholder function)
    return True  # True if there's activity, False if idle

def scale_dynos(quantity):
    # Scale dynos up or down
    data = {
        'updates': [
            {
                'type': 'web',  # Type of dynos to scale (e.g., 'web' or 'worker')
                'quantity': quantity,  # Number of dynos to scale to
            }
        ]
    }
    response = requests.patch(HEROKU_DYNOS_URL, headers=HEADERS, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Dynos scaled successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to scale dynos:", response.text)

def monitor_dyno():
    global last_activity_time
    while True:
        if check_activity():
            last_activity_time = time()
        else:
            if time() - last_activity_time > IDLE_TIMEOUT:
                print("Dyno has been idle for too long, scaling down...")
                scale_dynos(0)  # Scale down to 0 dynos
                break
        sleep(300)  # Check every 5 minutes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    monitor_dyno()


Thank you for the response, Thomas. I really appreciate your suggestion. I was wondering if there are multiple dynos running in Heroku for example 15,20 then would it show information for 15,20 dynos?
